cant login as sudo --> errormessage: sudo: unable to initialize PAM: Critical error - immediate abort

i want to shorten my password via: "sudo vim /etc/pam.d/common-password", during editing this file the editor crashed.
i tried to recover it with "vim -r /etc/pam.d/common-password" but this went wrong.
now i cant login as sudo, see that now the file /etc/pam.d/common-password is missing.
i had a copy before i start playing but i cant copy it back to /etc/pam.d/ because sudo needed
with "vim -r /etc/pam.d/common-password" the file ".common-password.swm" is created, dont know what todo with it.
i didnt try to restart the system  because i am afraid i cant login
See attached screenshots and my backupfile
the experts probably already noticed that i am not an expert but learning, hopefully there is an easy solution, should be great if somebody can help me. Please let me know if more info/files is needed.

THANKS
Regards Gijs van Cuijk
copy common-password file

gijs@gijs-ThinkPad-L560:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
gijs@gijs-ThinkPad-L560:~$

In step 2 what does this went wrong mean?
